# How to create navigation controller in a non-root controller view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

My application setup is like this:
I have a navigation controller (create in the app delegate)
View 1 --Push--->View2---Push--->View3 ---Modal transit (slide up) --->View4 --->Push-->View5

What I want to do is to create a new navigation controller in View4 so that I can push to another view from view5

I didn't have experience of creating navigation controller in view other than root view controller.

Can someone give me some guide or instructions for how to implement it?

Comment: oh.... i have programmatically created it and its quite easy
  yourOrderViewController *postingVC = [[yourOrderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourOrderViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    
    YourOrderViewController = postingVC;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:postingVC];
    
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

```
+ (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithNavigation
{
    id controller = [[**YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER** alloc] initWithNibName:**FOO** bundle:**BAR**];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    [controller release];
    return [navController autorelease];
}
```

I present this view over the root view controller using:

```
UIViewController *controller = [**YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER** viewControllerWithNavigation];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

You, of course, can present t over any view you want

Answer (score 0):

select view4 in your storyboard, and select the menu Editor -> Embeded In -> Navigation Controller. good luck.